# Scaffolding or another framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Im a little confused. I saw some code in one of the projects where we use Linq To SQL

```
<MetadataType(GetType(Customer.CustomerMeta))> Partial Public Class Customer
Friend Class CustomerMeta

    <Required(), StringLength(50)> Public Name As String
    <Required(), StringLength(50)> Public Address As String
    <Required(), StringLength(20)> Public EmailAddress As String
    <StringLength(20)> Public Country As String
End Class
```

And wasnt sure why it was created like this but it looked like a different method had been used from what im used to.

After reading around it seemed like the technique maybe Scaffolding (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488469(v=vs.90).aspx) but half way through this walkthrough i realised that many areas dont exist (like the global.asax file) or apply to the project i saw the above code in therefore i could be on the wrong track here.

Does anyone know what technique/framework is being used above and if there are articles i could refer to, to get up to speed? If books or training course is required here then again im happy for someone to point me towards the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Linq To SQL uses a code generation tool. I think its T4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are data validation annotations (I don't know the exact 'framework' using them in your case, as they're exposed in the .NET framework and anyone programming against it can use them): basically, you can decorate members with these attributes ([`ValidationAttribute`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx)) and this metadata can then be used to do some validation, either manual or automated by some data schema rule checker.

In this case, the property `Name` is:-

- a required field (i.e. it must have something in it, and not be empty),
- and must be 50 characters in length

And so on and so forth.

The latter constraint might make the former redundant, depending on what's analysing the rules.

Comment: The [`StringLengthAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) specifies the maximum length of a string, not the minimum, making `Required` *not* redundant. This is independent from who analyzes the rules.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth [Depends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx): _'Specifies the minimum and maximum length of characters that are allowed in a data field.'_ Even then, it's also dependent on the rule checker.

Comment: Not when using the constructor with one parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.stringlengthattribute.aspx. It only specifies the maximum length.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth There is only one constructor. But it can be explicitly specified; or, a rule checker is free to interpret the input as an absolute constraint (i.e. must be _no more or less than `StringLength` input_).

Comment: Indeed. What I meant was actually "when not setting the `MinimumLength` property". The code of the OP simply doesn't make the `Required` attribute redundant. This statement of yours is incorrect, especially in the given context (LINQ to SQL).

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Again, not necessarily. These attributes don't enforce themselves, and hence _'might'_. And that's in context with the rest of my answer.

Comment: I don't know why you are saying this. The default value of `MinimumLength` is 0. So how would any sane rule engine interpret this as *not less than `MaximumLength`*? It just makes no sense. MinimumLength = 0 means that it can be empty. Every rule engine interpreting it differently is bogus.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth There is _every possibility_ that this attribute can be used, by any given engine, to be interpreted one of two ways - LinqToSql does it the 'proper way', sure, but these aren't exclusive to it, they're a public API. After typing out two comments to try and placate you, I'm done; scratch that. These rules _do not enforce themselves_, and, _an implemented rule checker might well do something unexpected (however sane or insane to either party - but that's what documentation is for)_ - which you very well know.

Comment: I don't need to be placated. You just need to understand that the attribute specifies a contract. A rule engine that does not conform to the contract and interprets the attribute differently to what is specified in the documentation is bogus. If you want to account for bogus rule engines, you should remove your whole answer, because the attributes can be interpreted by such an engine in any possible and impossible way, making it impossible to say *anything* about the meaning.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth No, because it's still within the bounds of meaninfulness and doesn't stretch the imagination, whereas _'anything'_ would. And just downvote me if you think this is an incorrect answer, as you're surely not going to persuade me otherwise.

Comment: Interpreting `MinimumLength = 0` as anything else than "*the minimum length of the string has to be zero characters*" is not meaningful at all. It is arbitrary. About the downvote: I just don't like that one sentence at the end. For me that's not enough reason to downvote.